# Delete Button/Component of a specifc message (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

I am now trying in vain to remove buttons from a bot message. I have created a command for this purpose. When executing it, it should at best remove a specific, the last or at least all buttons that are on a specific message.

I have tried various things, but in all attempts the buttons are not removed.

```
module.exports = {
category: 'Utilities',
description: 'Delete Buttons',
permissions: ['ADMINISTRATOR'],

callback: async ({ client, message }) => {
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get('the channel id')
    channel.messages.fetch('the message id').then(msg => msg.edit({components: []}));
    console.log(msg)
    }
}
```

When I try to do this, I get the following console error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'messages')

When I try this, I neither get a console log, nor does the bot do anything ...

```
const { Client, Message } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  category: 'Utilities',
  description: 'Delete Buttons',

  permissions: ['ADMINISTRATOR'],

callback: async ({ client, message }) => {
    client.on('ready', async () => {
            const channel = client.channels.cache.get('the channel id')
                channel.messages.fetch('the message id').then(msg => {
                msg.edit({ components: [] })
            });
        },
    )}
  }
```

Maybe one of you knows a solution or an idea. :)
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I try this, I neither get a console log, nor does the bot do anything

The second example does not do anything because you are creating a ready event handler on running your command. Meaning, it's waiting for the bot to once again be "ready", i.e. the state of having logged in to the API as it does on startup. But your bot is already ready, and will not become ready again until the next time it restarts, so nothing will happen.

As for the first example, the error you are getting suggests `channel` is `undefined`, meaning either:

**A)** You have the incorrect channel ID
- OR -
**B)** The specified channel is no longer in the channel cache

If you are 100% sure the ID is correct, we can assume the issue you are having is the latter (the channel not being in the cache). There are many ways to solve this, but one simple way is to simply fetch the channel similar to how you are trying to fetch the message. Here's an example:

```js
const channel = await client.channels.fetch('the channel id');
const msg = await channel.messages.fetch('the message id');
msg.edit({components: []});
```

That should fix the issue. If it doesn't, then the issue is much more complicated and not enough information has been provided. Also note that in the above example, I swapped `Promise` syntax for `async/await` since you are using an `async` function anyways; I did this just to make this answer more readable, you can choose whichever format you prefer.

Comment: Hey Cannicide! Many thanks for the explanation! I have checked it out again and I can understand your first explanation (A). I have used your second suggestion and it works great!